# Getting [Amazon](500150) Connection reset by peer in Spark/Redshift specific query

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, databricks

I'm running spark 2.0.0 with databricks spark-redshift 2.0.1 on emr in cluster mode and my job works fine with some simple redshift queries like

```
val easyQueryWorks =
  s"""
     |select
     |s.session_id, s.user_id,
     |e.ex_id, e.pre_id
     |from schem1.sessions s
     |join schem2.entries e
     |on s.session_id = e.session_id
     |where e.entry_id = 200
     """.stripMargin
```

This result set has about 100,000 rows.

When I try to run it with a query that looks like this:

```
val loadQuery =
  s"""
     |select
     |          e.created_at, e.session_id, e.entry_id,
     |          t1.user_id,
     |          t1.dim1, t1.dim2, t1.dim3,
     |          c.p_id, c.name,
     |          s.dim0,
     |          s.dim1, s.dim2, s.dim3, s.dim4,
     |          s.dim5, s.dim6, s.dim7,
     |          s.dim8, s.dim9, s.dim10
     |        from
     |          schem1.entries e
     |        left join
     |        (
     |         select
     |            session_id, MAX(id) as id
     |         from
     |           schem1.tool_events
     |         where
     |           value in (1,2,3,4)
     |         group by
     |           session_id
     |         ) t2
     |         on
     |           t2.session_id = e.session_id
     |        left join
     |          schem1.tool_events t1
     |        on
     |         t1.id = t2.id
     |        join
     |          schem2.cooks c
     |        on
     |          c.id = e.entry_id
     |        join
     |          schem1.sessions s
     |        on
     |         s.session_id = e.session_id
     |        where
     |          e.entry_id = 200
    """.stripMargin
```

(if query is slightly incorrect please ignore. I just replaced the names of tables and fields)

After about 2 hours (we see in s3 a temp directory is created and has some files in there), and we get this exception:

**FATAL CampaignJob: [Job Name -> MyJob] java.sql.SQLException: Amazon Error setting/closing connection: Connection reset by peer.
java.sql.SQLException: Amazon Error setting/closing connection: Connection reset by peer.
        at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.channels.MessagesSocketChannel.readMessages(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.channels.AbstractMessagesSocketChannel.read(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.GeneralException: Amazon Error setting/closing connection: Connection reset by peer.
        ... 2 more**

And the job fails.

It is around the same number of rows as the easy query, we know that redshift access is fine given the easy query. The original query itself works straight on Redshift itself and takes about 7-8 min to run. Just that when it is run through spark using the databricks-redshift tool, it fails.

Let me know if I can provide anymore information.